# real transformer power factor

Tags: transformer

For a transformer having input and output power factor what do they depend on?
And if I want to find the transformer power factor is there a certain formula to get the overall power factor for a real transformer?

[image]

Source:

PE Electrical and Computer: Power Reference Handbook

Reference Handbook Version 1.1.1

Comment: Measure both sides...

Comment: It's completely load dependent. So, start by stating the load impedance and also start by assuming the load is resistive.

Comment: Look at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/354768/power-factor-of-a-transformer-does-it-have-anything-to-do-with-load-impedance/354770#354770